# json post log data every open info

Tags: json, web-services, web, logging, iis

For the mobile application to run in Flutter, I made user login, listing, adding, deleting etc. operations via database connection via Json web service.

One of them is the login process. The username and password values are given as parameters and the process works in the post method. This is not visible on the link on the url and is spinning in the background, but

When you look at the Windows Server IIS site logs, it says login?username=abcd&password=1234 as in the image below, because the full address of each visited page is written.

The red place in the image is the time, the blue place is the fixed ip address, the green place is the page name, the orange place is the external ip address visiting the site, that is, the web service.

Yes it's my server, it's my data and no one else can see it but what can I do to make it not so obvious and security?

Regards..

[image]

Log path file; C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\

Comment: If you want to hide the contents of your log files, you can uncheck the Standard fields checkbox in the iis Logging function, it will not log your logs.

Comment: Then nothing happens? My goal is to protect private and personal data in fact

Comment: You can encrypt your files, IIS does not provide encryption, you need to encrypt the file using an external method.